# Burning the Image binaries to eMMC device

Tags: boot, emmc

I would like to copy/burn Image binaries to the eMMC device on development boards directly using a USB cable without using the GDB tool which is RISC-V architecture. I would like to copy the binaries to hundreds of boards at a time. Is there any tool to access the eMMC device with Ubuntu OS?

Comment: If the boards expose the eMMC to an external connection then anything can be used in any OS. If not then the answer is likely no, you need that tool.

Comment: Can you suggest, if we want to write a tool for copying the binaries to an eMMC device, what prerequisites need to be taken?